# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._onLineConfigured is not a function

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i am trying to call a js function from another function. But I am getting an error.

***.js**

```
    reset: async function (record, ev) {
      // var self=this;
      if (ev && ev.target === this) {
          this.restoreProductTemplateId = this.recordData.product_template_id;
          this.optionalProducts = (ev.data && ev.data.optionalProducts) || this.optionalProducts;
      }
      console.log('this',this);
      await this._super(...arguments);
        if (ev && ev.target === this) {
            if (ev.data.changes && !ev.data.preventProductIdCheck && ev.data.changes.product_template_id) {
              console.log('inside if');
                this._onTemplateChange(record.data.product_template_id.data.id, ev.data.dataPointID);
            } else if (ev.data.changes && ev.data.changes.product_id) {
              console.log('inside else if');
                this._onProductChange(record.data.product_id.data && record.data.product_id.data.id, ev.data.dataPointID).then(wizardOpened => {
                    if (!wizardOpened) {
                      console.log('inside wizardOpened',wizardOpened);
                        console.log('this',this);
                        this._onLineConfigured();
                        // this.amhere();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    _onLineConfigured: function(){
      // alert('am here 77777777777');
      var ff = 0.0;
      console.log('ff',ff);
      var self = this;
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);

      var parentList = self.getParent();
      var unselectRow = (parentList.unselectRow || function() {}).bind(parentList); // form view on mobile
      if (self.optionalProducts && self.optionalProducts.length !== 0) {
              self.trigger_up('add_record', {
                  context: self._productsToRecords(self.optionalProducts),
                  forceEditable: 'bottom',
                  allowWarning: true,
                  onSuccess: function () {
                      // Leave edit mode of one2many flist.
                      unselectRow();
                  }
              });
          }else if (!self._isConfigurableLine() && self._isConfigurableProduct()) {
                  // Leave edit mode of current line if line was configured
                  // only through the product configurator.
                  unselectRow();
              }
    },
```

ow can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the fact that you are accessing an inner `this` in the `.then` body. The solution is to define an outer this an access it instead of the inner `this`:

```js
   reset: async function (record, ev) {
      ...
      // This should fix it
      outer_this = this;
      ...
      this._onProductChange(record.data.product_id.data && 
      record.data.product_id.data.id, ev.data.dataPointID).then(wizardOpened => {
                    if (!wizardOpened) {
                        // Note that I am accessing the outer this
                        outer_this ._onLineConfigured();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    _onLineConfigured: function(){
      ...
    },
```